# Automatic WhatsApp Mesaage send from Google Sheet if anythng change

Tags: whatsapp-stickers

I want to know if there is a way, if there is something change in a specific cell automatic WhatsApp should send

Answer (score 0):

First register in https://panel.rapiwha.com/landing/login.php.
Link your phone and get the API key from the web site.
Then try the below code in your Google Sheet.

```
//
function onEdit(e) {
  var api_key="xxxxxxx"; //from the Rapiwah web site
  var mob="919123456789"; // with country code without +
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(), r ;
  var shtn=s.getName();
  if(shtn=="Plan") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    r = e.range; 
    var old=e.oldValue;
    var nval=r.getValue();
    var linecol = r.getColumn();
    var linerow = r.getRow();
    if(linerow === 3 && linecol===4 ) { //checks the B3 cell was changed
      var wpurl= 'https://panel.rapiwha.com/send_message.php?apikey='+api_key+'&number='+mob+'&text=Cell B3 in Plan Sheet changed from '+old+' to ' + nval;
      var formurl3 = wpurl.replace(/#/g, "");
      var formurl4 = formurl3.replace(/,/g, "");
      var formurl = formurl4.replace(/ /g, "%20");
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formurl);
    }
  }
}
//
```